# How to handle views on top of the FlipView?

Tags: android, always-on-top, flipview

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip) that allows flipping between views like the "[FlipBoard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flipboard.app)" app.

It works quite well.

The problem is that I need to put a few views on top of it, so I've put it inside a FrameLayout, and the rest of the views after it.

It looks ok, but it has a problem:

When flipping, the views that are on top of it change their transparency (and even become hidden) till the flip is over.

How can I handle this problem?

---

EDIT: I've found [this library](https://github.com/emilsjolander/android-FlipView) which doesn't have this problem, but it has a weird color transition while flipping that I wish to avoid.

---

EDIT: I've found out that this is a known issue ([#49](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip/issues/49)) . Would love to know if anyone else has an idea of how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix this library, but it seems this library works fine :

https://github.com/emilsjolander/android-FlipView

Not sure though how customizable it is compared to the one i've tested.